# Python Pandas: propagate value on conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I try to propagate a value from one row to the next and I'm not sure where to start (pandas).

For one user,

- if some values come from the source **B**, I want to replace it with the values from the date just before.
- If there is no date before, I want to keep the value in B.
- Lines from source A should not change

Source data:

| USER | Date | Value | Source |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | 01/01/2023 | 1000 | A |
| USER1 | 01/02/2023 | 1200 | A |
| USER1 | 02/02/2023 | 1300 | A |
| USER1 | 20/02/2023 | **1000** | **B** |
| USER1 | 01/07/2023 | 1400 | A |
| USER2 | 01/01/2023 | 1000 | A |
| USER2 | 01/02/2023 | 1200 | A |
| USER2 | 02/02/2023 | **1250** | **B** |
| USER2 | 20/02/2023 | 1300 | A |
| USER2 | 01/07/2023 | 1400 | A |

Target data:

| USER | Date | Value | Source | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| USER1 | 01/01/2023 | 1000 | A |  |
| USER1 | 01/02/2023 | 1200 | A |  |
| USER1 | 02/02/2023 | 1300 | A |  |
| USER1 | 20/02/2023 | **1300** | **B** | get its value "1300" from the previous date of the same user |
| USER1 | 01/07/2023 | 1400 | A |  |
| USER2 | 01/01/2023 | 1000 | A |  |
| USER2 | 01/02/2023 | 1200 | A |  |
| USER2 | 02/02/2023 | **1200** | **B** | get its value "1200" from the previous date of the same user |
| USER2 | 20/02/2023 | 1300 | A |  |
| USER2 | 01/07/2023 | 1400 | A |  |

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"USER" : ["USER1", "USER1", "USER1", "USER1", "USER1", "USER2", "USER2", "USER2", "USER2", "USER2"],
    "Date" :["01/01/2023", "01/02/2023", "02/02/2023", "20/02/2023", "01/07/2023", "01/01/2023", "01/02/2023", "02/02/2023", "20/02/2023", "01/07/2023"],
    "Value" :["1000", "1200", "1300", "1000", "1400", "1000", "1200", "1250", "1300", "1400"],
    "Source" :["A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "A"]}
)
```

Comment: could you have 2 or more consecutive `B` rows/values?

Comment: Can you have NaNs in the original Series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the dates are already sorted, you could [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html), [`groupby.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.ffill.html), and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) in case there was no previous value:

```
m = df['Source'].eq('B')
df['Value'] = (df['Value'].mask(m)          # mask B values
               .groupby(df['USER']).ffill() # replace with previous non-B
               .fillna(df['Value'])         # if still NaN, replace with original
               #.mask(df['Value'].isna())
              )
```

*NB. if you can have NaNs in the original Series, uncomment the last line.*

Output:

```
    USER        Date Value Source
0  USER1  01/01/2023  1000      A
1  USER1  01/02/2023  1200      A
2  USER1  02/02/2023  1300      A
3  USER1  20/02/2023  1300      B
4  USER1  01/07/2023  1400      A
5  USER2  01/01/2023  1000      A
6  USER2  01/02/2023  1200      A
7  USER2  02/02/2023  1200      B
8  USER2  20/02/2023  1300      A
9  USER2  01/07/2023  1400      A
```

Comment: Seems perfect. I don't have the "pandas way of thinking yet" with that many steps :) Thanks!

Comment: @Nico note that if you have NaNs in the original Series, there are other options depending on the exact expected output. Here it's propagating the last valid value per ID ;)

Comment: OK, *now* I can congratulate you on 200k. I've certainly got plenty of value from all those answers.

Comment: @Nick thanks! The feeling is shared, it's always a pleasure to read you :)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work for you?

```
#Ignore this if your date isn't a string
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d/%m/%Y')

# Sort the DataFrame by "USER" and "Date"
df.sort_values(by=['USER', 'Date'], inplace=True)

#Replace value when Source = B with the value in the row above it 
#Value in row above should be the closest date per user due to the sorting above
for index, row in df.iterrows():
if row['Source'] == 'B' and index > 0 and df.at[index - 1, 'Source'] == 'A' and df.at[index - 1, 'USER'] == row['USER']:
    df.at[index, 'Value'] = df.at[index - 1, 'Value']
```

Comment: Looks like it would work. It feels like using for loops is not the "pandas way of thinking" but I havent compared the performances with the other answer. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: I agree. I just can't think of a way around it without it right now :/ I'm sure once one of the senior contributors has a look at this, they'll suggest something more panda-esque :) This can just be the band aid until then!

Comment: Check @mozway answer it's great :)