# how can I set value with a previous condition?

Tags: python, pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({'price': [1,2,8, 9, 3,5,20,8,7,1,2,3,4,6, 10, 15,9,8, 6, 75,1, 3, 20,30, 5, 4,31, 25, 8]})

df.loc[df['price']> 10, 'case'] = 'buy'

df.loc[df['price']< 5, 'case'] = 'sell'

Hey, I have this database and there are two condition : price > 10 and price < 5 .It still the number between 5 and 10 without condition.
[image]

What I need : when the condition "buy" is True still True und get the number between 5 and 10 "buy" value until the "sell"  condition become True .
And when the condition "sell" is True still True und become the number between 5 and 10  "sell" value until the "buy" condition become True.
I will be thankful if someone  help me, Tanks.

Comment: Is your output exhaustive? row 5 should remain empty? why? Or do you want a simple `df['case'] = df['case'].ffill()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this may be what you're looking for?

```
df['case'].fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Taken from what I learnt from @mozway here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77202261/python-pandas-propagate-value-on-conditions/77202383?noredirect=1#comment136127650_77202383